# Angular Directive placed on ng-repeat not removed from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS directive meant to interact with notifications pushed from a server. The problem I am having is that currently the method I am using is to have an ng-repeat which keeps track of all the notifications during the session, and then displaying them as they are added to the array. What I want to happen, is that an alert comes, it's added to the DOM, it stays for a couple seconds, and removes itself from the DOM. At this point the issue is that the element will hide, but it will not remove itself from the DOM. Being that the element is absolutely positioned, after the fadeout is prevents me from accessing item that it is in front of. I assumed that `element.remove()` and the `element.$destroy()` would do the trick, but it seems like the element is not being from the `ng-repeat` or possibly that the `$scope` of the directive is not being deleted. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
angular.module('bmuApp').directive('messageNoti', function($timeout){
  return {
    scope: {
      alert: '=messageNoti'
    },
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: 'partials/authenticated/homepage/alerts.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         $timeout(function(){
            element.addClass('fadeOut');
            $timeout(function(){
              element.remove();
            }, 500);
         }, 5000);

        element.on('$destroy', function () {
          scope.$destroy();
        });
       }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<!------------>
<!-- Alerts -->
<!------------>

    <div class="alert-container" ng-cloak>
      <a class="alert animated fadeInUp" ng-repeat="alert in alerts" ng-href="messages/{{ alert.user.thread_id }}" message-noti="alert">
      </a>
    </div>

<!-----Template for Alert------>

    <div class="row">
      <span class="close">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
      </span>
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-left">
        <span class="profile-image" style="background-image:url('https://www.blackmarketu.com/{{ ::alert.user['profile-picture'] }}');"></span>
        <h5> {{ ::alert.user["user-firstname"] }}&nbsp;{{ ::alert.user["user-lastname"] }} </h5>
        <p>{{ ::alert.message }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to interact with the DOM directly to remove it. Just splice (remove) that array member from the array.

So your logic is a bit wrong, because you have an array of alerts and you are not removing them, you just want to remove the DOM element.

If you don't want to change your code too much and add a parent directive to handle this, you can pass both "alert" (current array member) and "alerts" (entire array of alerts) to your directive and then in your timeout callback instead of removing the DOM element, you splice that array member from the array.

Comment: Using `alerts: '=messageArray'` in combination with`scope.alerts.splice(alert, 1);` fixed my problem. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `replace: true`. Since the `ng-repeat` directive creates *inherited* scopes and your directive creates *isolate* scope, they won't play well together on the same element.

From the Docs:

> `replace` ([DEPRECATED!], will be removed in next major release - i.e. v2.0)
>
> specify what the template should replace. Defaults to `false`.
>
> - `true` - the template will replace the directive's element.
> - `false` - the template will replace the contents of the directive's element.

-- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api)

From GitHub:

> [Caitp--](https://github.com/caitp) It's deprecated because there are known, very silly problems with `replace: true`, a number of which can't really be fixed in a reasonable fashion. If you're careful and avoid these problems, then more power to you, but for the benefit of new users, it's easier to just tell them "this will give you a headache, don't do it".

-- [AngularJS Issue #7636](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7636)

Comment: This did help but didn't fix my problem. Look @ answer above.